# How to enable option to keep app's data on uninstall prompt?

Tags: android

There seems to be a new option on Android 10 to allow the user to save an app's data before they uninstall it, I assume it'll be saved on the user's Google drive account along with other apps' data.

Going through all the new Android 10 features and APIs I didn't find any reference to this. Does anyone know how to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the following declaration in the application element of manifest XML:

`android:hasFragileUserData="true"`

The documentation is for this declaration is:

> If `true` the user is prompted to keep the app's data on uninstall

Comment: It looks like on Samsung devices this flag is true on default. (Android documentation say default is false)
If you don't like it set it explicit do false

Comment: @Gugelhupf On my Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra, it's not true by default. It wasn't on my S10 either.

Comment: It keeps the app data on the device while uninstalling the app itself. It won't be stored on Google Drive as far as I know. Because when users install an unofficial version of my app, then uninstall while keeping app data, they cannot install the official version anymore. This is a huge problem. I think it's because of the different signatures.

Answer (score -1):

i believe this is actually the same feature that existed from android 6 and up trough

```
android:allowBackup
android:fullBackupContent
```

but in earlier android versions it was done without promting the user, while in android 10 the user needs to confirm that the data is stored.

Comment: documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

Comment: I'm currently testing this on Android 10 and it doesn't trigger the checkbox.

Comment: @JohnSardinha did you find a solution for android 10 ?

Comment: This is something completely different. android:hasFragileUserData="true" keeps the app data on the device while the allowBackup is stored on Google Drive